# CamelBlueprintTestSupport and blueprint property placeholders in camelContext

Tags: java, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to rewrite a unit test that was previously using a spring context to use the blueprint context and `CamelBlueprintTestSupport`. I've been seeing different errors on different executions and in the course of trying to get it working I updated `camel-test-blueprint` to version `2.15.3`. Now it always fails with the same error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
```

The underlying issue is that a property placeholder cannot be resolved:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property placeholder key: xyz not found
at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintPropertiesParser.parseProperty(BlueprintPropertiesParser.java:164) ~[camel-blueprint-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
```

We use blueprint property placeholders in our camel context and route definitions. I assume there is nothing special about that.

I tried to create a simple test project to reproduce the problem and actually managed to get the context to start in that test project, however applying the same steps to my actual project does not solve the problem there.

In my test project I have the following simple setup:

**blueprint.xml**

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="appConfig" persistent-id="app" update-strategy="reload" />

<camelContext id="demoContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" autoStartup="{{demo.sync}}" >
    <route id="demoRoute" autoStartup="{{demo.route.startup}}">
        <from uri="timer:test" />
        <to uri="log:test" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

**Test class**

```
public class RouteTest extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected String getBlueprintDescriptor() {
        return "OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml";
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("demo.sync", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        return props;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] loadConfigAdminConfigurationFile() {
        URL cfg = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("app.cfg");
        return new String[] { cfg.getPath(), "app" };
    }
```

I found that without overriding `useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent` to return something for the placeholder on `camelContext` it will not work at all.
By overriding `loadConfigAdminConfigurationFile` I got it to load the actual properties to replace the second placeholder.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a race condition so I was wondering if somebody got the blueprint property placeholders working with `CamelBlueprintTestSupport` and could give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this test class provided by Claus Ibsen. It should give you hints on how to solve the issue.
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-test-blueprint/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/test/blueprint/ConfigAdminLoadConfigurationFileTest.java

Comment: If you look at my code you'll see that I'm already doing that. Problem is that it is not working in every setup e.g. in my simple test project it works but as soon as I do that in the real project it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `protected String useOverridePropertiesWithConfigAdmin(Dictionary props)` as the way to override properties in the blueprint successfully, have you tried using it? Example:

```
protected String useOverridePropertiesWithConfigAdmin(Dictionary props) {
    props.put("demo.sync", true); //Add your properties in
    return "app"; //return pid
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, yes. But I don't want to have to override all properties in the test, I actually want it to load the real properties.